# Как сделать затемнение другим цветом, при наведении на фото?

Tags: html, css, css3, css-animation

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы когда я наводил на фотографию - появлялась стрелочка и фото покрывалось другим цветом с прозрачностью (фото прикрепил ниже). Уже сломал голову, гуглил, спрашивал, но так и не нашел ответ. Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь! Спрашивал похожий вопрос, но он был про затемнение, из-за чего и отметил тот вопрос отмеченным.
Код сейчас:

```
<div class="collection__menu">
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <div class="collection__item">
                                <img src="img/photo_shop1.png" alt="Фото товара" class="collection__img">
                                <a href="#" class="collection__arrow"></a>
                                <h3 class="collection__subtitle">Футболка USA</h3>
                                <span class="collection__sale">$229</span>
                                <span class="collection__price">$129</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <div class="collection__item">
                                <img src="img/photo_shop2.png" alt="Фото товара" class="collection__img">
                                <a href="#" class="collection__arrow"></a>
                                <h3 class="collection__subtitle">Купальник Glow</h3>
                                <span class="collection__price">$129</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <div class="collection__item">
                                <img src="img/photo_shop3.png" alt="Фото товара" class="collection__img">
                                <a href="#" class="collection__arrow"></a>
                                <h3 class="collection__subtitle">Свитшот Sweet Shot</h3>
                                <span class="collection__price">$129</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.collection__menu {
    align-items: center;  
    display: flex;  
}

.collection__item {
    text-align: center;
}

.collection__img {
    margin-top: 85px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.collection__subtitle {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 27px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.collection__sale {
    color: #9C9C9C;
    text-decoration-line: line-through;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.collection__price {
    color: #998E78;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
}
```

То, как должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: для чего отметили решением прошлый вопрос ? в данный момент ваш вопрос дубликат

Comment: @MaximLensky Я не совсем там корректно задал вопрос, и на тот вопрос, который задал - по сути дали ответ, теперь перезадал вопрос.

Comment: наверно так: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/yLJeLgE - оно ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

почему бы не попробовать сделать стиль `:after` в виде прямоугольника того же размера, что и фотка с задним фоном с заданной прозрачностью?

например так:

```
<style>

.image {
    position:   relative;
    width:      300px;
    height:     300px;
    
    border:     1px solid black;
}

.image img {
    width:      300px;
    height:     300px;
}

.image:hover:after {
    content:    "";

    position:   absolute;
    left:       0;
    top:        0;
    
    width:      300px;
    height:     300px;
    
    background: white;
    opacity:    20%;    
}

</style>

<div class = 'image'>
    <img src = 'https://cs.pikabu.ru/images/big_size_comm/2013-05_3/13684731208281.jpg'>
</div>
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую, благодарю.

Comment: @Dikkkey, добавил примерчик

Comment: Всё, с помощью всех ответов, которые нашел — сделал) Спасибо большое!